# Yaw problem in my wall following algorithm

Tags: ros, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a wall following algorithm, but I'm having some problem. Essentially my code use laser to extract a line and calculate the slope (locally to the robot, so from 0 to 2*pi) but to make the control I need the robot yaw (0 to 3.14 and -3.14 to 0) so when I have a negative yaw for example -1.59 and a slope of 1.61 my error that is error=(slope-yaw). Causes the robot turn to the wrong direction :(

Somebody already have the same problem with angles in ROS ?

Gabriel Oliveira

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45006/yaw-problem-in-my-wall-following-algorithm/) by [leivas_gabriel](https://answers.ros.org/users/404/leivas_gabriel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using an error in an angle to feed a controller you generally need to wrap the error to be between -pi and pi as well.  The way I normally do this is with the mod function in whatever language you're using.  For example, the following will give an error that is always between -pi and pi

```
error=mod(slope-yaw+2*PI,2*PI)-PI
```

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0